# istio 0.2.7 helloworld app init proxy_init stuck at podinitializing

Tags: istio

Installing Istio for the first time in Kubernetes 1.7.9. Installed with automatic sidecar injection. When trying the sample applications, although the side car and the application containers are started and in "running' state, the proxy_init is stuck at PodInitializing and the overall Pod state is at Init:0/1.

```
[root@node-8 helloworld]# kubectl describe pods helloworld-v1-3194034472-12rgj 
Name:           helloworld-v1-3194034472-12rgj
Namespace:      default
Node:           node-8/136.225.226.159
Start Time:     Wed, 01 Nov 2017 19:13:11 +0100
Labels:         app=helloworld
                pod-template-hash=3194034472
                version=v1
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"helloworld-v1-3194034472","uid":"5212bc02-bf30-11e7-b818-0050560...
                sidecar.istio.io/status=injected-version-0.2.7
Status:         Running
IP:             192.168.144.130
Created By:     ReplicaSet/helloworld-v1-3194034472
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/helloworld-v1-3194034472
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:
    Image:              docker.io/istio/proxy_init:0.2.7
    Image ID:
    Port:               <none>
    Args:
      -p
      15001
      -u
      1337
    State:              Waiting
      Reason:           PodInitializing
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment:        <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-76kq4 (ro)
Containers:
  helloworld:
    Container ID:       docker://aa89ecc46d273b76d71a0f67d5169519926cc0e01d9d1f2ab960e2b88a46013b
    Image:              istio/examples-helloworld-v1
    Image ID:           docker-pullable://docker.io/istio/examples-helloworld-v1@sha256:c671702b11cbcda103720c2bd3e81a4211012bfef085b7326bb7fbfd8cea4a94
    Port:               5000/TCP
    State:              Running
      Started:          Wed, 01 Nov 2017 19:13:14 +0100
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Requests:
      cpu:              100m
    Environment:        <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-76kq4 (ro)
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:       docker://9bb16159d42229512892feae13614c4c373f3436957b6263c772f62282d75e02
    Image:              docker.io/istio/proxy:0.2.7
    Image ID:           docker-pullable://docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:910546c29a32e11f58bab92e68513a5c8f636621c0e20197833270961fda3713
    Port:               <none>
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      -v
      2
      --configPath
      /etc/istio/proxy
      --binaryPath
      /usr/local/bin/envoy
      --serviceCluster
      helloworld
      --drainDuration
      45s
      --parentShutdownDuration
      1m0s
      --discoveryAddress
      istio-pilot.istio-system:8080
      --discoveryRefreshDelay
      1s
      --zipkinAddress
      zipkin.istio-system:9411
      --connectTimeout
      10s
      --statsdUdpAddress
      istio-mixer.istio-system:9125
      --proxyAdminPort
      15000
    State:              Running
      Started:          Wed, 01 Nov 2017 19:13:15 +0100
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:         helloworld-v1-3194034472-12rgj (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:    default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:       (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
      /etc/certs/ from istio-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-76kq4 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Initialized   True 
  Ready         True 
  PodScheduled  True 
Volumes:
  istio-envoy:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
  istio-certs:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: istio.default
    Optional:   true
  default-token-76kq4:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-76kq4
    Optional:   false
QoS Class:      Burstable
Node-Selectors: <none>
Tolerations:    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath                   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------                   --------        ------                  -------
  4m            4m              1       default-scheduler                                       Normal          Scheduled               Successfully assigned helloworld-v1-3194034472-12rgj to node-8
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8                                         Normal          SuccessfulMountVolume   MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "istio-envoy" 
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8                                         Normal          SuccessfulMountVolume   MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-76kq4" 
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8                                         Normal          SuccessfulMountVolume   MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "istio-certs" 
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.initContainers{istio-init} Normal          Pulled                  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxy_init:0.2.7" already present on machine
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.initContainers{istio-init} Normal          Created                 Created container
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.initContainers{istio-init} Normal          Started                 Started container
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.containers{helloworld}     Normal          Pulled                  Container image "istio/examples-helloworld-v1" already present on machine
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.containers{helloworld}     Normal          Created                 Created container
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.containers{helloworld}     Normal          Started                 Started container
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.containers{istio-proxy}    Normal          Pulled                  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxy:0.2.7" already present on machine
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.containers{istio-proxy}    Normal          Created                 Created container
  4m            4m              1       kubelet, node-8         spec.containers{istio-proxy}    Normal          Started                 Started container
[root@node-8 helloworld]# kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
helloworld-v1-3194034472-12rgj   0/2       Init:0/1   0          12m
helloworld-v2-717720256-rc06f    0/2       Init:0/1   0          12m
sleep-140275861-vjqf7            0/2       Init:0/1   0          1h
[root@node-8 helloworld]#
```

Initializers is enabled:

```
[root@node-8 istio-0.2.7]# kubectl api-versions | grep admi
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1
[root@node-8 istio-0.2.7]#
```

From the istio-Proxy logs,

```
[2017-11-02 19:40:19.323][14][warning][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:164] initializing epoch 0 (hot restart version=8.2490552)
[2017-11-02 19:40:19.330][14][warning][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:332] starting main dispatch loop
[2017-11-02 19:40:19.392][14][warning][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:316] all clusters initialized. initializing init manager
[2017-11-02 19:40:19.427][14][warning][config] external/envoy/source/server/listener_manager_impl.cc:451] all dependencies initialized. starting workers
[2017-11-02 19:41:19.429][14][warning][main] external/envoy/source/server/drain_manager_impl.cc:62] shutting down parent after drain
```

but the proxy_init is stuck at waiting state.

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Istio sidecars can be automatically injected into a Pod before deployment using an alpha feature in Kubernetes called Initializers.  Please ensure your cluster has the initializer alpha feature enabled.  For example, this requires deploy an alpha cluster in GKE.   In IBM Bluemix container service, alpha feature should be already enabled in 1.7.x k8s cluster.

Comment: Thanks Lin.  Its already enabled. Update the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

After further research, figured that there is a known issue that got fixed in 1.8 where the init container can wait at PodInitializing state. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/51644. works in 1.8 fine.